How to run the anaconda-ks.cfg file from the linux cmd
I recently purchased an iot development kit, and the only file that I think is bootable is a file named anaconda-ks.cfg. I've looked online and assume that the file will generate, install, and boot the OS from the file. The problem is I don't know how to do it, and I can't find any sources online that explain how. If someone can help me, I'd prefer to be given a direct answer, not a direction to another online article. Please help if you can. Thanks
